# How do I view only answered featured questions on SO?

Tags: support, bounties

Is there a way to view old featured questions (bounty reward) on SO?  ...and possibly view them by category, like Java or C++?

If not, is there a way to create a suggestion for it?

I seem to learn a great deal from reading the current questions and would like to read the old ones, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks.

Note: I think the tags could be improved on this question to reach more of the community.

Comment: Should probably go to meta (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've just written up a query on data-explorer that does this.

[Answers awarded bounties by tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/894/answers-awarded-bounties-by-tag?Tag=java)  (E.g. Java)